# Upgrading Rails 3.2 to 4.1 issues.. Forced to use Requires?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in the process of upgrading an older Rails 3.2 application to 4.1 and am having an issue with prereqs in that I am having to add a "require" line to my application.rb file for each of my gems in order to get them to load.

This can't be right..  Previously devise, paperclip, pusher, rescue, rolify, stripe..etc would load and work perfectly without doing this.  Now I have to add the following to the application rb file at top for them to work.

```
require 'devise' 
require 'paperclip'
require 'pusher'
require 'resque'
require 'rolify'
require 'stripe'
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong in my conversion.  Thoughts?  Why am I forced to add requires?

I have written other Rails 4.1 apps from scratch and never had to do this so I'm not sure why its making me do it here..

I'm also using RVM if that's possibly the issue?

Any help or thoughts you might have would be very much appreciated.

Comment: OH.. Ahha.. I think I might have found it, apparently there is a new config setting I didn't know about.  
  
# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

Answer (score 0):

Yep that was it.

In Rails 4.0 they added the following to the application.rb file that wasn't in my 3.2 file.

```
# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)
```